# Construct XSLT file to add details from XML document to sub groups

Tags: xml, xslt

I am extremely new to anything related to XML, but I was hoping someone here could help me.  How do you create an XSLT file such that the value within a parent is added as a new item in each child group (in my rough example below, adding the person name into both "Group1" sections and both "Group2" sections").

If I can see what a working example would be, I should be able to adapt things from there.  Thanks ahead for your help.

This would be the input:

```
<List>
    <People>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <age>25</age>
        <Group1>
            <name>Group 1, Item 1</name>
            <text>Some descriptive text relating to Group 1 Item 1.</text>
        </Group1>
        <Group1>
            <name>Group 1, Item 2</name>
            <text>Some descriptive text relating to Group 1 Item 2.</text>
        </Group1>
        <Group2>
            <name>Group 2, Item 1</name>
            <text>Some descriptive text relating to Group 2 Item 1.</text>
        </Group2>
        <Group2>
            <name>Group 2, Item 2</name>
            <text>Some descriptive text relating to Group 2 Item 2.</text>
        </Group2>
    </People>
</List>
```

And this would be my desired output:

```
<List>
    <People>
        <name>Bob</name>
        <age>25</age>
        <Group1>
            <pname>Bob</pname>      
            <name>Group 1, Item 1</name>
            <text>Some descriptive text relating to Group 1 Item 1.</text>
        </Group1>
        <Group1>
            <pname>Bob</pname>      
            <name>Group 1, Item 2</name>
            <text>Some descriptive text relating to Group 1 Item 2.</text>
        </Group1>
        <Group2>
            <pname>Bob</pname>      
            <name>Group 2, Item 1</name>
            <text>Some descriptive text relating to Group 2 Item 1.</text>
        </Group2>
        <Group2>
            <pname>Bob</pname>      
            <name>Group 2, Item 2</name>
            <text>Some descriptive text relating to Group 2 Item 2.</text>
        </Group2>
    </People>
</List>
```

Comment: Your question would be a lot clearer if it included an example of the expected output (assuming the above is the input). As it is, I am guessing you want to fetch the value (or copy the entire node) of the sibling (from the context of `Group1` or `Group2`) `name` - e.g. by calling `<xsl:value-of select="../name"/>`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have added the desired output to my original post.

Comment: As a first step, do not put the words "XSLT" and "script" together, not even in your head.  *Especially* not in your head.  It inclines you to thinking about XSLT in procedural terms, and that's couterproductive because XSLT is not a procedural language.

Comment: Noted! I have adjusted my original post to (hopefully) be more appropriate.

Comment: When you want a stylesheet that transforms the input into similar output, the usual place to start is with an identity transform.  Google can help you discover what that looks like.  Then write a template(s) for the element(s) that should differ between input and output.  Google can help you with general information about writing XSLT templates.  *We*, however, are neither a tutorial service nor a coding service.  Have a go at it yourself, and if you encounter specific difficulties then those are the kinds of topics we take up here.

Comment: #s in element names should really be avoided, use group id=1, so you can iterate through every group.